# GWT Forum Advice, which widget to use

Tags: gwt, forum

I need to implement a forum using gwt. Can somebody advice me a widget which is best suited, I am using the normal gwt, no ext ...

Comment: Why do you have to make an entire forum in GWT? The technology is focused on more of a dynamic sort of web application, and forums tend to focus on displaying fairly static content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create your own Widget (i.e. Composite) for this. The view would probably be an HTMLPanel (use SafeHTML for forums, it's perfect for that) with some labels and links on top for time of posting, poster, etc. Those may be put in a VerticalPanel when displaying and the editor may be a RichTextArea. There is no such thing as a generic forum widget.